# Solve $9x^8\equiv 8\pmod{17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

$$9x^8\equiv 8\pmod{17}$$
Is there a way to solve this with out testing all integers $x$ between $1$ and $17$ ?

Comment: Bad news: there are 8 possible values for x.

Comment: @DanUznanski: That's actually good news. It means you only need to test $10$ values before you find a proper one (which abides to OP's requirement for doing it without testing all $17$ options). Heck, you even made it in less than $60$% effort.

Comment: I see... I'm still working on it..  how did you solve it so fast ?xD

Comment: More good news: $8 = (17-1)/2$. So there are only two values for $x^8$

Comment: I brute forced it with the giant expensive calculator that sits on my desk. 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, and 14 all satisfy the equation.

Comment: @DanUznanski: It's symmetric around $8.5$ by the way. Starting from $1$, from $16$ or from the middle, you could find a proper value within no more than $3$ attempts.

Comment: Yeah, that's generally obvious.  Alternately, these numbers are 3, 5, 6, 7, -7, -6, -5, -3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For even powers, you only ever need to test half the range anyway, eg

$$ (17-x)^2 = (17-x) (17-x) = 17(17-x)-17x+x^2 \equiv x^2 \bmod 17 $$

Then add $\{17-x_i\}$ into your answer set $\{x_i\}$

In this case, with $8=16/2$ (and $17$ prime), we also know that $x^{16} \equiv 1 \bmod 17$ (excluding $x=17k$) and that  $x^8 \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 17$. We need $x^8\equiv -1 \bmod 17$ in this case. Testing the lower half of the digits, $x=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ shows answers for $\{3,5,6,7\}$ which meet our needs.

---

Note that we could test whether *any* answer was feasible before we even started raising numbers to specific powers, which was a nice side effect of having $(p-1)/2$ as the exponent.